# unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Fid1Instruments"). Expected elements are <{http://proba.org/proba}Fid1Instruments>

Tags: java, namespaces, jaxb

I had this exception: `unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Fid1Instruments"). Expected elements are <{http://proba.org/proba}Fid1Instruments>`

i have package-info.java file:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://proba.org/proba")
package com.enum1.instruments;
```

in the main class i do this:

```
JAXBContext jx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Fid1Instruments.class);
Unmarshaller u = jx.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<?>  ue= (JAXBElement<?>) u.unmarshal(new File("ex1.xml"));
```

In the generated java file:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "fid1Bond"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Fid1Instruments", namespace="http://proba.org/proba")
```

I read answers for same problems, but they doesn't work.

Comment: The problem might be in your `ex1.xml` file. Can you post that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your mappings JAXB is expecting your document to look like the following where the element `Fid1Instruments` is qualified by the namespace `http://proba.org/proba`.

```xml
<ns:Fid1Instruments xmlns:ns="http://proba.org/proba">
    ...
</ns:Fid1Instruments>
```

And you are currently passing it:

```xml
<Fid1Instruments>
    ...
</Fid1Instruments>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html